# QGIS Strange behaviour when saving gpx file to shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gps, gpx

Have recently been forced to change from using DNRGPS to download (mostly) waypoint data from Garmin eTrex GPS (for some reason corporate IT withdrew making DNRGPS available for download - no idea why DNRGPS was no longer available - and we cannot run a standalone .exe file ). We are standardised on using ArcGIS as the main GIS platform but this is not available to all users. One of our group devised a method to download using QGIS (which is available to all users to install), however his method was not producing a time field in the shapefile - we used to get time with DNRGPS (as both the UTC/GMT time and our local Aust EST). As the most literate  GIS user in the group (and the only who seems to care that we do  not have a time field) I have been trying to solve the problem.

The download method has been to select the gpx file in the QGIS browser and export to shapefile. On my system I can see the time field and select this (plus name) as fields for the exported shapefile, which gives me half of what I want (thime is UTC/GMT rather than local AEST). When I am logged onto the computer that the person who normally is tasked with the downloads uses, I can also see the time field. Howver when she is logged onto this system she cannot see the time field. Same computer, different users logged on.

Can anyone point me to a reason why I can see the time field, but the other user on the same computer cannot? One other users who ocasionally does the downloads on his system also cannot see the time field, I had assumed that we had a difference in QGIS configuration or install but apparently not.

I did have an elegant solution to replace DNRGPS with a custom ArcGIS model tool, but there is apparently some reluctance within the organisation (state government department) to extend ArcGIS to 'non core' users so this is not a viable solution at the moment. The GPS downloads have recently shifted from one section (who are all Arc users) to my group who are mainly not Arc users.

Comment: Shapefile doesn't support time in a date field (just YYYYMMDD). This is just one of its many flaws. I suggest you use a different format.

Comment: Yes I know that shapefiles do not support datetime fields. The export should result in a datetime string in a text field- which is what I get when I export using the described process. I can't understand why I can see datetime when I go to export to shapefile (when selecting fields in the gpx file to export), but another user on the same computer and looking at the same gps file cannot see the datetime field (which is named time). The gpx file has the datetime string in it,